# Como crear un número de div determinado por una variable con un contenido determinado

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Quería saber como se puede crear un número determinado de div y que estos tengan un contenido. Es decir, Lo que quiero es que dependiendo del valor de una variable llamada $var, se creen este numero de div. Por ejemplo, si la variable tiene como valor 4, que se creen 4 div y que contengan el mismo contenido que un div anterior con cierta clase y cierto  id. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? H einvestigado y he visto que con la opcion createelement se pueden crear divs, pero estos divs no son iguales a otro. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.
Los div creados serían iguales a este div:

```
<div id="comentariosdiv" class="comentariosdiv">
  <h1 class="comentariostitulo">Comentarios</h1>
  <?php $sql="SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE idpublicacion = $idpublicacion ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $autor = $mostrar['nombre'];
    $comentario = $conn->real_escape_string($mostrar['comentario']);
    ?>
  <?php echo $mostrar['comentario'] ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Y esto lo quieres en javascript?  Lo digo porque no se si vale la pena hacerlo asi, sino más bien hacerlo directamente en PHP, ya que la variable $var tiene pinta de ser de PHP.  Si lo haces en PHP solo tienes que encerrar ese código en un `for` o un `foreach` que la recorra.  Si por lo contrario lo quieres en javascript, puedes usar `queryselector`, `cloneNode` y `after` como puedes ver [aquí](https://codepen.io/cferdinandi/pen/RwwVmyO)

Comment: @masterguru Muchísimas gracias. Como siempre, gran ayuda. Eres mi puto idolo. Ojalá ayudes a mucha gente y te vaya bien en la vida. Te camelo.

Comment: jaja, no se que decirte, me siento abrumado, pero tampoco creo que sea para tanto. Que yo sepa justamente a ti solo he intentado ayudarte dos veces, y en la otra no se si terminastes consiguiendo arreglar nada con mis indicaciones, creo mas bien que no, pero bueno, te agradezco tus palabras, solo pretendo ayudar como bien dices, aunque me equivoco como todos muchas veces :-)

Answer (score 1):

Para ello puedes usar el método `cloneNode` combinado con un ciclo `for`, y luego estableces un `id` distinto a cada elemento basado en el índices;

```
//Esta variable representa el número de copias que deseas obtener
let copies = 4;
//Este es el contenedor que deseas clonar
let div = document.getElementById('comentariosdiv');
//Aquí almacenarás las copias
let divs = [];
for(let i = 0; i < copies; i++) {
    divs[i] = div.cloneNode(true);
    divs[i].id = `comentario_${i}`;
}
```

> El método `cloneNode()` devuelve un duplicado del nodo en el que este método fue llamado.
> Puedes consultar más sobre este método en la documentación de [MDN-Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

Para agregar estos contenedores al DOM puedes usar el método `append()`:

```
let copyDiv = document.getElementById('copiaComentarios');
for(let i in divs {
    copyDiv.append(divs[i]);
}
```

Comment: Dos cosas. ¿Cómo hago para que estos nuevos divs creados se tengan un id distinto al inicial? Es que creo que no se ven porque se imprimen uno encima del otro.  ¿O dónde se imprimen estos divs? Porque no me aparecen. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No los veo no se porque.

Comment: Edité la respuesta.